# Removing unwanted characters in each line of a file then matching what is left to another file in Python

Tags: python, matching

I would like to write a python script that addresses the following problem:

I have two tab separated files, one has just one column of a variety of words.  The other file has one column that contains similar words, as well as columns other information. However, within the first file, some lines contain multiple words, separated by " /// ".  The other file has a similar problem, but the separator is " | ".

**File #1**

```
RED
BLUE /// GREEN
YELLOW /// PINK /// PURPLE
ORANGE
BROWN /// BLACK
```

**File #2** (Which contains additional columns of other measurements)

```
RED|PINK 
ORANGE
BROWN|BLACK|GREEN|PURPLE
YELLOW|MAGENTA
```

I want to parse through each file and match the words that are the same, and then append the columns of additional measurements too.  But I want to ignore the `///` in the first file, and the `|` in the second, so that each word will be compared to the other list on its own.  The output file should have just one column of any words that appear in both lists, and then the appended additional information from file 2.  Any help??

---

**Addition info / update:**

Here are 8 lines of File #1, I used color names above to make it more simple but this is what the words really are:  These are the "symbols":

```
ANKRD38  
ANKRD57  
ANKRD57
ANXA8 /// ANXA8L1 /// ANXA8L2  
AOF1  
AOF2  
AP1GBP1  
APOBEC3F /// APOBEC3G
```

Here is one line of file #2:  What I need to do is run each symbol from file1 and see if it matches with any one of the "synonyms", found in file2, in column 5 (here the synonyms are A1B|ABG|GAP|HYST2477).  If any symbols from file1 match ANY of the synonyms from col 5 file 2, then I need to append the additional information (the other columns in file2) onto the symbol in file1 and create one big output file.

```
9606  '\t'    1 '\t'    A1BG  '\t'   -   '\t'       A1B|ABG|GAB|HYST2477'\t'    HGNC:5|MIM:138670|Ensembl:ENSG00000121410|HPRD:00726    '\t' 19   '\t'  19q13.4'\t' alpha-1-B glycoprotein '\t' protein-coding '\t' A1BG'\t'    alpha-1-B glycoprotein'\t'  O '\t'  alpha-1B-glycoprotein '\t'  20120726
```

File2 is 22,000 KB, file 1 is much smaller.  I have thought of creating a dict much like has been suggested, but I keep getting held up with the different separators in each of the files.  Thank you all for questions and help thus far.

Comment: Your problem seems like a general programming puzzle. At least show us some ideas/code you have. We will guide you the right way.

Comment: This isn't all that tough, but you need to consider things like what happens when a word in file 1 matches several lines in file 2 - do you append the additional columns? Merge in some way? Just use the latest one found? I'm sure there are plenty of people here who can give you basic tips, but if you're after complete code there are some more details needed. Two (small) example files and the output from them would be a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

After your comments below, I think this is what you want to do. I've left the original post below in case anything in that was useful to you.

So, I think you want to do the following. Firstly, this code will read every separate synonym from file1 into a `set` - this is a useful structure because it will automatically remove any duplicates, and is very fast to look things up. It's like a dictionary but with only keys, no values. If you *don't* want to remove duplicates, we'll need to change things slightly.

```
file1_data = set()
with open("file1.txt", "r") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        file1_data.update(i.strip() for i in line.split("///") if i.strip())
```

Then you want to run through file2 looking for matches:

```
with open("file2.txt", "r") as in_fd:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as out_fd:
        for line in in_fd:
            items = line.split("\t")
            if len(items) < 5:
                # This is so we don't crash if we find a line that's too short
                continue
            synonyms = set(i.strip() for i in items[4].split("|"))
            overlap = synonyms & file1_data
            if overlap:
                # Build string of columns from file2, stripping out 5th column.
                output_str = "\t".join(items[:4] + items[5:])
                for item in overlap:
                    out_fd.write("\t".join((item, output_str)))
```

So what this does is open file2 and an output file. It goes through each line in file2, and first checks it has enough columns to at least have a column 5 - if not, it ignores that line (you might want to print an error).

Then it splits column 5 by `|` and builds a `set` from that list (called `synonyms`). The `set` is useful because we can find the *intersection* of this with the previous set of all the synonyms from file1 very fast - this intersection is stored in `overlap`.

What we do then is check if there was any overlap - if not, we ignore this line because no synonym was found in file1. This check is mostly for speed, so we don't bother building the output string if we're not going to use it for this line.

If there was an overlap, we build a string which is the full list of columns we're going to append to the synonym - we can build this as a string once even if there's multiple matches because it's the same for each match, because it all comes from the line in file2. This is faster than building it as a string each time.

Then, for each synonym that matched in file1, we write to the output a line which is the synonym, then a tab, then the rest of the line from file2. Because we split by tabs we have to put them back in with `"\t".join(...)`. This is assuming I am correct you want to remove column 5 - if you do not want to remove it, then it's even easier because you can just use the line from file2 having stripped off the newline at the end.

Hopefully that's closer to what you need?

**ORIGINAL POST**

You don't give any indication of the size of the files, but I'm going to assume they're small enough to fit into memory - if not, your problem becomes slightly trickier.

So, the first step is probably to open file #2 and read in the data. You can do it with code something like this:

```
file2_data = {}
with open("file2.txt", "r") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        items = line.split("\t")
        file2_data[frozenset(i.strip() for i in items[0].split("|"))] = items[1:]
```

This will create `file2_data` as a dictionary which maps a word on to a list of the remaining items on that line. You also should consider whether words can repeat and how you wish to handle that, as I mentioned in my earlier comment.

After this, you can then read the first file and attach the data to each word in that file:

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as fd:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as fd_out:
        for line in fd:
            words = set(i.strip() for i in line.split("///"))
            for file2_words, file2_cols in file2_data.iteritems():
                overlap = file2_words & words
                if overlap:
                    fd_out.write("///".join(overlap) + "\t" + "\t".join(file2_cols))
```

What you should end up with is each row in `output.txt` being one where the list of words in the two files had at least one word in common and the first item is the words in common separated by `///`. The other columns in that output file will be the other columns from the matched row in file #2.

If that's not what you want, you'll need to be a little more specific.

As an aside, there are probably more efficient ways to do this than the O(N^2) approach I outlined above (i.e. it runs across one entire file as many times as there are rows in the other), but that requires more detailed information on how you want to match the lines.

For example, you could construct a dictionary mapping a word to a list of the rows in which that word occurs - this makes it a lot faster to check for matching rows than the complete scan performed above. This is rendered slightly fiddly by the fact you seem to want the overlaps between the rows, however, so I thought the simple approach outlined above would be sufficient without more specifics.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful, I added some information that may help clarify my issue more, if you have any insight that's much appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: It actually looks slightly easier that way because file1 only contains symbols so you can read them into a `set` for fast lookups. However, I think I'm still misunderstanding. Are you just trying to "filter" the lines from file2 which match at least one symbol from file1? Or do you always expect to find a match for every line? Thing is, if all you do is look for exact matches to file1, you're not *adding* any data because that symbol is already in col 5 of file2. You see what I'm getting at? Hence I assume I'm missing something - is "match" more complicated than just matching a string?

Comment: Yes you're right, I am not adding data, I see where my explanation was confusing now. If there is a match to a symbol from file1, I want to duplicate the rest of the data that goes with its synonym in file2, and make a new row of data. I thought `append` would be helpful here but I will look into `set`. When you have suggest `"///".join` in your code, is that to reinsert a separator between the matched symbol and synonym? I guess that is the difference, I would like the matches to be in separate rows. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: OK, sorry to be pedantic here, but the detail is really important. So basically everything in file1 is a separate symbol, right? So `foo /// bar` is the same as `foo` and `bar` on different lines for your script? And the data you want to duplicate from file2, does that include the other synonyms? Or just all the columns *except* column 2? And yes, the `///` was to re-insert separators, but I'm not sure if that's what you want to do or not so you might not need it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to what I now think you want. Hopefully this is at least closer! :)

Comment: Yes, this is definitely along the lines of what I am going for.  I appreciate your help so much!  The only problem is I am running the code and it does not seem to be appending on the columns of additional information.  Not sure the problem, but I will keep troubleshooting.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hm, that's odd - I just did a quick test case and the code seems to be working as I'd expect. I did just make one simple edit to make sure empty tokens don't end up in `file1_data`. Perhaps try printing the contents of `items`, `synonyms` and `overlap` each time round the second loop, see if that helps track down the problem?

Comment: Yes that helped, just a small problem with the synonyms part.  Thank you again!  File looks great!

Comment: If that's answered your question, could accept the answer, please? (The green tick at the top left of the answer). It'll make sure everyone knows the issue is dealt with so they don't waste time reading through it.

Comment: One more question Cartroo.  I am trying to print the symbols that did not match any synonyms.  I was thinking of using the `^` operator.  Is this what you would do?  I would want to write it to a separate file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to keep a set of *all* the items found in file2 to do that - so, add `file2_synonyms = set()` just prior to the file2 loop and run `file2_synonyms.update(synonyms)` each time around the loop. At the end you can then use `file1_data ^ file2_synonyms` to find the items in either file but not both. Let's say you instead want items in file1 but not file2 only, you can use `file1_data - file2_synonyms`, or reverse it for the other way around. It just depends what you need.

Comment: Great, one more thing.  I realize there will be more matches if I change the synonyms to being all in uppercase.  However, once the synonyms are a set this is not possible.  And if I make them a string then uppercase, then a set, each letter is separate.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you're passing a string where an iterable (e.g. a list or set) is expected. If you iterate over a string it acts like a list of individual characters. As long as you don't mind losing the original capitalisation, just replace the two occurrences of `i.strip()` with `i.strip().upper()` in my example code to force all items to uppercase before adding them to the set. Of course, all lowercase would work equally well.

Comment: Well thank you again. Again a question (I apologize for so many, but thank you again for being so helpful). A few of the synonyms have an added letter or number at the end preventing a match from occuring(e.g. `HYST2477` does not match the 'symbol' `HYST247`). Once I have changed the data to a set I do not think I can use regular expressions to match things. What would be the best way to make sure these matches occur? I am working on another short script to run separately, because I wasn't sure if this current code could be altered to make those matches happen.

Comment: If you can transform the synonyms in advance (e.g. stripping off all digits) then you can continue to use a `set` to store the items. Currently we're doing `i.strip().upper()`, and that can be amended to any arbitrary transformation we wish. However, if you want to do some form of "fuzzy matching" where you look for a prefix match then you need to find a different approach. This is because `set` (like `dict`) relies on [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to perform quick comparisons. For example, you could use lists and compare items in sequence, but it'll be rather slower.

Comment: I am revisiting a similar problem that I think is a quick fix, so I thought I would ask you.  I now want to do something similar to what I first asked (match information in two columns) but now I would like to append additional information from not one file, but two files.  In the words of this problem, the file1_data set is not just one column anymore, but multiple columns of information, but only the first column will match the other file still.  I think I would just add another loop, but I seem to get an output file with all the same information repeated line by line.

Comment: You can use the same code but maintain an additional dictionary which maps a key from the `file1_data` set into the set of additional columns from the other files. Whenever you produce an output row, look up `item` from `overlap` in the additional dictionary and merge in the columns. I suggest using both a `set` and `dict` because a `dict` alone doesn't offer a fast intersection method like `set` does (as far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html for file i/o
2. Loop through each line in each file

   file1set = set(file1line.split(' /// '))

   file2set = set(file2line.split('|'))

   wordsineach = list(file1set & file2set)

split will create an array of the color names

set() turns it into a set so we can easily compare differences in each line

1. Loop over 'wordsineach' and write to your new file

Answer (score 0):

Use the `str.replace` function

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1:
    content1 = f1.read()
    content1 = content1.replace(' /// ', '\n').split('\n')
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    content2 = f2.read()
    content2 = content1.replace('|', '\n').split('\n')
```

Then use a list comprehension

```
common_words = [i for i in content1 if i in content2]
```

However, if you already know that none of the words in each file are the same, you can use set intersections to make life easier

```
common_words = list(set(content1) & set(content2))
```

Then to output the remainder to another file:

```
common_words = [i + '\n' for i in common_words]  #so that we print each word on a new line

with open('common_words.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(common_words)
```

As to your 'additional information', I cannot help you unless you tell us how it is formatted, etc.